# Search in php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a hierarchical array in my project like this:

```
$Array = array(
    array(
        'Id' => 1,
        'Title' => 'Some Text1',
        'Children' => array(
            array(
                'Id' => 11,
                'Title' => 'Some Text11',
                'Children' => array(
                    array(
                        'Id' => 111,
                        'Title' => 'Some Text111',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'Id' => 112,
                        'Title' => 'Some Text112',
                        'Children' => array(
                            array(
                                'Id' => 1121,
                                'Title' => 'Some Text1121',
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'Id' => 12,
                'Title' => 'Some Text12',
                'Children' => array(
                    array(
                        'Id' => 121,
                        'Title' => 'Some Text121',
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'Id' => 2,
        'Title' => 'Some Text2',
    )
);
```

I want to search my string (such as 'Some Text1121') in `'Title'` index in this array and return it's path such as after search `'Some Text1121'` I want to return this result:

```
"1 -> 11 -> 112 -> 1121"
```

Or when I Search 'Some' string, return all path in array.
please help me, thanks.

Comment: Do you want exact match or list of similar? Please share if you tried anything?

Comment: You need recursive function for do that.

Comment: That's not a task that can be solved with a simple built in function. A custom recursive function will be involved. But it's on you to start somewhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've quickly written you something. It's not perfect, but you get the idea:

```
<?php

function searchRec($haystack, $needle, $pathId = Array(), $pathIndex = Array()) {
    foreach($haystack as $index => $item) {
        // add the current path to pathId-array
        $pathId[] = $item['Id'];
        // add the current index to pathIndex-array
        $pathIndex[] = $index;
        // check if we have a match
        if($item['Title'] == $needle) {
            // return the match
            $returnObject = new stdClass();
            // the current item where we have the match
            $returnObject->match = $item;   
            // path of Id's (1, 11, 112, 1121)
            $returnObject->pathId = $pathId; 
            // path of indexes (0,0,1,..) - you might need this to access the item directly
            $returnObject->pathIndex = $pathIndex; 
            return $returnObject;
        }

        if(isset($item['Children']) && count($item['Children']>0)) {
            // if this item has children, we call the same function (recursively) 
            // again to search inside those children:
            $result = searchRec($item['Children'], $needle, $pathId, $pathIndex);
            if($result) {
                // if that search was successful, return the match-object
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// useage:
$result = searchRec($Array, "Some Text11");
var_dump($result);

// use 
echo implode(" -> ", $result->pathId);
// to get your desired 1 -> 11 -> 112
```

*EDIT*: rewritten to make the function actually return something. It now returns an Object with the matching item, the path of Id's and the path of (array-) Indexes.

Comment: Thanks my friend.

Comment: I think this is very nice,