# Error when calling function it self, VCS say="undifined function"

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I got this function from a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074506/search-in-php-multidimensional-array). when I try on a separate file it runs normally. but when I rewrite it in a class that contains more functions I can rather call it in another file, the searchRec contained in this function (calling the function itself) turns red or is marked as an error by visual studio code. whereas before, above this function I also wrote the same function in which there is a function call itself, and it runs normally.

```
public function searchRec($haystack, $needle, $pathId=Array(), $pathIndex=Array())
{
    foreach($haystack as $index => $item) {

        $pathId[] = $item['Id'];

        $pathIndex[] = $index;

        if($item['Title'] == $needle) {

            $returnObject = new stdClass();

            $returnObject->match = $item;   

            $returnObject->pathId = $pathId; 
            item directly
                $returnObject->pathIndex = $pathIndex; 
            return $returnObject;
        }

        if(isset($item['Children']) && count($item['Children']>0)) {
            (recursively) 

                $result = searchRec($item['Children'], $needle, $pathId, $pathIndex); //searchRec error, VCS say: undifined function

            if($result) {

                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a class method, you need to call it with object-oriented syntax.

```
$result = $this->searchRec($item['Children'], $needle, $pathId, $pathIndex);
```

Comment: what I'm confused about is, why when I run this code in a separate file I don't need to add $ this->?

Comment: When you called the function you had to use `$something->searchRec(...)` didn't you? It's a class method, it has to be called on an object.