# Find last array from multidimensional array and get the index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on multidimensional arrays and find cases similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074506/search-in-php-multidimensional-array). After I tried it turned out I had to have the id and unique value sought, so it was different from my case.

so my case goes like this: I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => null
            [count] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [Dagadu Bocah] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Dagadu Bocah
                            [count] => 47
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [HirukPikuk] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => HirukPikuk
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [DGD] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => DGD
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [DGD] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => DGD
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                            [count] => 2
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

what I'm looking for is how to search for arrays, for example 'DGD' it will produce all indexes ending in array 'DGD'

```
DGD => Dagadu Bocah->HirukPikuk,
       Dagadu Bocah;
Malioboroman=> Dagadu Bocah->DGD,
       Dagadu Bocah;
```

what I've tried is like this, with the final result using implode:

```
public function searchRec($haystack, $needle, $pathId=Array(), $pathIndex=Array())
{
  foreach($haystack as $index => $item) {
    $pathId[] = $item['count'];
    $pathIndex[] = $index;
    if($item['item'] == $needle) {
        $returnObject = new stdClass();
        $returnObject->match = $item;   
        $returnObject->pathId = $pathId; 
        $returnObject->pathIndex = $pathIndex; 
        return $returnObject;
    }

    if(isset($item['child']) && count($item['child']>0)) {
        $result =searchRec($item['child'], $needle, $pathId, $pathIndex);
        if($result) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
$result = searchRec($Array, "Some Text2");
echo implode(" -> ", $result->pathId);
```

Comment: why not try something like foreach($arrays as $array) { end($array); $key = key($array); var_dump $key; }

Comment: you have typo on `count($item['child']>0)` - the `)` in the wrong place - it should be `count($item['child'])>0`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but it might help you solve your issue(s).

Function `pathFinder()` is a recursive function, i.e. it will call itself as many times as needed to traverse your subject array.

Just set the `needle`, i.e. the `key` you're looking for, and it returns all paths to the key in your subject array.

**An example of its use:**

We have an array `$arr` with three keys called `one`, we're going to use the function to find the paths to all three keys:

```
$arr = [
    ['one' => 'once', 
     'two' => ['one' => 'twice', 'two' => 'twice', ['one' => 'thrice']], 
     'three' => 'once',]
];

$needle = 'one'; // the key we're looking for
$result = pathFinder($arr, $needle); // invoke function

/**
 * function pathFinder() returns the path(s) to a key in an array.
 *
 * @param array  $arr    the subject array
 * @param string $needle the key we're looking for
 *
 * @return array            the paths leading to the key we're looking for
 */
function pathFinder(array $arr = [], $needle = ''): array
{
    static $path = '';
    static $paths = [];

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $path .= $key . "->";
            pathFinder($value, $needle);
        } else {
            if ($key === $needle) {
                $paths[] = $path . $key; // store path
            }
        }
    }
    return $paths; // return all found paths to key $needle
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0->one
    [1] => 0->two->one
    [2] => 0->two->0->one
)
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/QOpXI)